# How to assign a row collection (obtained by a linq query) to a datatable without using a loop?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, assign

I've scenario where the datatable may contain large number of rows. As a result i can't  iterate and update the datatable using a loop.

I am using the following code to get row collection,

```
         from row in CSVDataTable.AsEnumerable()
         where CSVDataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Any(col => !row.IsNull(col))
         select row;
```

Any one please tell me how to assign the result of the above code to a datatable without using a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I **could assign the Linq query result to a data table** by the following code,

```
           // Create a DataTable from Linq query.       

             IEnumerable<DataRow> query = from row in CSVDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                                            where CSVDataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Any(col => !row.IsNull(col))
                                            select row; //returns IEnumerable<DataRow>

             DataTable CSVDataTableWithoutEmptyRow = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

See the link for further details,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx

Comment: You are not avoiding looping through every `DataRow` though. It's only hidden in the implementation details of the extension method. Something to consider: I am not sure the extension method turns off the datatable's notifications, index maintenance, and constraints while loading rows. This can have a significant performance impact as it has to check and update everytime a row is added contrary to using `BeginLoadData` and `EndLoadData` where the checks are only done once at the end. Check documentation or compare load times with the method I propose in my answer.

Comment: @InBetween, There should be some logic behind this. I am sure it won't be an inefficient looping. I guess it might be Bulkcopy or something like that. Simillarly we use lot of class library methods as such, where we are not bothering about the performance issues..

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to avoid the unavoidable I think.

You have a "lazy" query wich returns an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. This query will be enumerated no matter what when you try to access the `DataRow` collection it represents.

The only difference will be if you do it directly or some method of `DataTable` hides that implementation detail.

I'd do the following:

```
DataTable table;
table.BeginLoadData();
foreach (DataRow row in query)
{
     table.ImportRow(row);
}
table.EndLoadData();
```

Comment: It gives an error `Use of unassigned local variable 'table'`